# Assign single value to a single key from dictionary key with multiple values

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I have seen many forums on assigning multiple values to a key in python, but none going the other way. What I want is to assign a single key to a single value, and then flip it.

What I have:

```
myDict = {1: ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'], 2: ['id4', 'id5'], 3: ['id6']}
```

What I am looking to do:

```
myDict = {'id1': 1, 'id2': 1, 'id3': 1, 'id4': 2, 'id5': 2, 'id6': 3}
```

I have been searching the forums and cant figure out how to assign a single value to a single key, but I'm guessing the 'flip' part would look something like this:

```
myDict = {y:x for x,y in MyDict.iteritems()}
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

EDIT:
All id's will be unique (not chance of duplicates/multiples)

Comment: What if one id is in multiple lists?

Comment: Is there any possibility that one `id` can be in the multiple `value` lists?

Comment: you need to specify how you want to deal with collisions. Do you want to keep multiple values?

Comment: Sorry, each id will be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to nest 2 comprehensions, since you have a list of values for each of the key-value pairs in your original dict.

How about

```
{id:x for x,y in myDict.iteritems() for id in y}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot have duplicate ids across the lists, a relatively simple comprehension can do it:

```
>>> myDict = {1: ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'], 2: ['id4', 'id5'], 3: ['id6']}
>>> {id:k for k,lst in myDict.iteritems() for id in lst}
{'id6': 3, 'id4': 2, 'id5': 2, 'id2': 1, 'id3': 1, 'id1': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this via:

```
dict((x,k) for k, v in myDict.iteritems() for x in v)
```

OR:

```
{x: k for k, v in myDict.iteritems() for x in v}
```

OR (not a pythonic approach):

```
reverse_dict = {}
for k in a:
    for x in myDict[k]:
        reverse_dict[x] = k
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

```
{id:x for x,y in myDict.iteritems() for id in y}
```